# Parsing Hashie::Mash output to Json in ruby

Tags: ruby, json, hash, ruby-grape

I'm getting user input in JSON format for an API created using grape. In a particular parameter, I'm giving an array of JSON in the following format.

```
 "personal" : {
  "details" : {
   "firstname" :"nagalakshmi",
   "lastname" : "n"
  }
}
```

When I tried to print "personal" attribute it is showing like below

```
#<Hashie::Mash details=#<Hashie::Mash firstname="nagalakshmi" lastname="n">>
```

Is there any way to parse the attribute to  json format?

Comment: have you tried calling `#to_json` on it?

Comment: Make sure you answer the question the right way and click the check mark so this question can be answered. Comments are not the places for official answers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was able to do it using `to_json`

Answer (score 1):

I also got this same object as params with Grape.

```
Hashie::Mash

params: #<Hashie::Mash data=#<Hashie::Mash attributes=#<Hashie::Mash title="Ember Hamster"> type="pictures">>
```

If you are using Rails We can convert into ruby hash as following:

```
params.to_hash
```

gives

```
{"data"=>{"type"=>"pictures", "attributes"=>{"title"=>"Ember Hamster"}}}
```